# Detect sequences rowwise

Tags: r, dplyr, seq, rowwise

Please see the toy data to create the column "check" (solution). If there are 3 values in sequence (from 2018 to 2021, rowwise) which are >=20, the value should be TRUE otherwise FALSE.

A dplyr solution is preferred. The original dataset have hundreds of cols and thousands of rows. NAs could be anywhere.

```
test<-data.frame(country=c("US","UK","RU","GR","BE"),
             "y_2018"=c(NA,30,20,40,10),
             "y_2019"=c(10,10,20,20,20),
             "y_2020"=c(20,NA,30,20,20),
             "y_2021"=c(NA,70,10,10,NA),
             check=c(F,F,T,T,F))
```

Comment: for the sequence `30, 10, 20, 40` what will be the result?

Comment: good question. 30,10,20,40 -> FALSE.  But more than 3 in a sequence should also be TRUE (i.e.: 20,20,20,20->TRUE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using `rle` -

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(check = {
    tmp <- rle(c_across(starts_with('y')) >= 20)
    any(tmp$lengths[tmp$values] >= 3, na.rm = TRUE)
  }) %>%
  ungroup

# country y_2018 y_2019 y_2020 y_2021 check
#  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>
#1 US          NA     10     20     NA FALSE
#2 UK          30     10     NA     70 FALSE
#3 RU          20     20     30     10 TRUE 
#4 GR          40     20     20     10 TRUE 
#5 BE          10     20     20     NA FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

And another way without using dplyr (I changed the test data in order to include the `30, 10, 20, 40)` case):

```
test<-data.frame(country=c("US","UK","RU","GR","BE"),
                 "y_2018"=c(NA,30,20,30,10),
                 "y_2019"=c(10,10,20,10,20),
                 "y_2020"=c(20,NA,30,20,20),
                 "y_2021"=c(NA,70,10,40,NA),
                 check=c(F,F,T,T,F))

rownames(test) <- seq(1:nrow(test))


# Choose only rows whose number of columns with x >=20 is greater than 2
cond1  <- apply(test[2:5], 2, function(x) x >= 20)

cond2  <- apply(cond1, 1, function(x) length(which(x==TRUE)) > 2)

data1 <- data.frame(cond1[cond2,])


# Check if the condition of x>=20 is sequential across columns
aa <- ifelse(data1$y_2018 == data1$y_2019 & data1$y_2019 == data1$y_2020, TRUE, FALSE)

bb <- ifelse(data1$y_2019 == data1$y_2020 & data1$y_2020 == data1$y_2021, TRUE, FALSE)

cc <- data.frame(aa, bb)

cc$final <- ifelse(cc$aa==TRUE | cc$bb==TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)


# Select the appropriate rows
data2 <- data.frame(data1[cc$final,])

test2 <- test[rownames(data2),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dapply` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
library(data.table)
test$check <- dapply(get_vars(test, is.numeric), MARGIN = 1,
       FUN = function(x) any(table(NA^(x < 20)*rleid(x >= 20))>=3))
test$check
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```